# Cannot update user object in DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I can fetch my user dao in the DaoAuthenticationProvider implementation but I can't seem to update that same object. I want to increment the access failed count on unsuccessful logins but spring ends up throwing an exception.

I have tried auto-wiring an entity manager and creating a transaction independently and saving the user object but to no avail.

Here is the relevant service method call:

```
public void resetPassowrdAttempts(CorAclUser user) {
    user.setAccessfailedcount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
    userRepository.save(user); //Exception here
}
```

Here is the overrided method in DAO authentication provider. I haven't overrided any other methods.

```
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication){
    CorAclUser aclUser =  aclUserRepository.findById_UsernameAndId_UserTenantCode(userDetails.getUsername(),Constants.TENANT_CODE).orElseThrow( 
            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password."));
    if(!aclUser.getActiveFlag())
        throw new NotFoundException(ExceptionResponseCodes.USER_NOT_FOUND, "User is deactivated");
    if(userDetails.getAuthorities()!=null) {
        if(verifyHash(authentication.getCredentials().toString(),aclUser.getPasswordhash()) ) {
            userService.resetPassowrdAttempts(aclUser);
        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Password is incorrect!");
        }
    }else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("user does not have any privileges");
    }
}
```

Here is the error log:

[ate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl]:HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.tlx.configurations.security.CustomUserDetails]

Handling error: TransactionSystemException, Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Resolved [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]

Comment: try changing the additionalAuthenticationChecks() signature to take CustomUserDetails instead of UserDetails

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. You can update failed login attempts counter in catch block. Here's a sample code for you:

```
    try {
        // Perform the actual authentication.
        super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);

        // Reset login attempts number on successful login.
        user.setLoginAttemptsNumber(0);
    } catch (final BadCredentialsException e) {
        // Increase the number of unsuccessful attempts.
        user.setLoginAttemptsNumber(user.getLoginAttemptsNumber() + 1);

        if (user.getLoginAttemptsNumber() < maxLoginAttemptsNumber - 1) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(String.format("Incorrect username or password. Attempt %d of %d.",
                                                            user.getLoginAttemptsNumber(), maxLoginAttemptsNumber), e);
        }
    } finally {
        userDao.save(user);
    }
```